# LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean with Karaf, Spring, and JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, karaf

There are a number of scenarios where declaring data sources and persistence units in XML files are less than ideal.  To this end, I'm attempting to configure JPA using LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.  But first, some references which prove this approach works in a non-OSGI environment:

- www.baeldung.com/2011/12/22/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa/
- docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html

To this end, the source code for my Karaf OSGI bundle I've put together is as follows.

```
    public class AbstractXyzTableServiceImpl
    {
        private static EntityManagerFactory _entityManagerFactory;

        MysqlDataSource mysqlDataSource = null;


        // private static final SessionFactory configurationSessionFactory = buildConfigurationSessionFactory();

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource()
        {
            final MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();

            dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
            dataSource.setDatabaseName("PSH");
            dataSource.setUser("root");
            dataSource.setPassword("password");

            return dataSource;
        }


        @Bean
        public Properties hibernateProperties()
        {
            final Properties properties = new Properties();

            properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            // properties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "mysql-pool-xa");
            // properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");

            return properties;
        }


        public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory()
        {
            // _entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Config");

            if (_entityManagerFactory == null)
                _entityManagerFactory = getEntityManagerFactory(dataSource(), hibernateProperties());
            return _entityManagerFactory;
        }


        @Bean
        public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, Properties hibernateProperties)
        {
            final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
            //emfBean.setPersistenceUnitName("Config");
            emfBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
            emfBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "info.test.configuration.data" });
            emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
            emfBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);
            emfBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
            //emfBean.setPersistenceXmlLocation("META-INF/persistence.xml");
            emfBean.afterPropertiesSet();

            return emfBean.getObject();
        }

    }
```

Unfortunately, Spring/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean seems to insist on a corresponding persistence.xml file, for which all defined attributes may be overridden.  This is fine, except I can't get this code, when deployed within Karaf 4.0.0, to find the persistence.xml file.  The stack trace provided by Karaf is as follows:

```
    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Unable to resolve persistence unit root URL
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:591)[158:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-orm:4.1.6.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.preparePersistenceUnitInfos(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:443)[158:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-orm:4.1.6.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:424)[158:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-orm:4.1.6.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)[158:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-orm:4.1.6.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)[158:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-orm:4.1.6.RELEASE_1]
        at info.leonard.configuration.service.impl.AbstractConfigurationServiceImpl.getEntityManagerFactory(AbstractConfigurationServiceImpl.java:83)[195:leonard-configuration-businessLogic:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
        at info.leonard.configuration.service.impl.AbstractConfigurationServiceImpl.getEntityManagerFactory(AbstractConfigurationServiceImpl.java:67)[195:leonard-configuration-businessLogic:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
        at info.leonard.configuration.service.impl.ConfigurationDomainServiceImpl.createDomain(ConfigurationDomainServiceImpl.java:80)[195:leonard-configuration-businessLogic:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
        at info.leonard.configuration.command.domain.CreateDomainCommand.execute(CreateDomainCommand.java:34)[195:leonard-configuration-businessLogic:0.0.1.SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.commands.basic.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:34)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.compat.CommandTracker$1.execute(CommandTracker.java:109)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:67)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.osgi.secured.SecuredCommand.execute(SecuredCommand.java:87)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:480)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:406)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:182)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:119)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:94)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at org.apache.karaf.shell.impl.console.ConsoleSessionImpl.run(ConsoleSessionImpl.java:267)[43:org.apache.karaf.shell.core:4.0.0]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[:1.7.0_60-ea]
    Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
        at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getURL(ClassPathResource.java:187)[155:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-core:4.1.6.RELEASE_1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:588)[158:org.apache.servicemix.bundles.spring-orm:4.1.6.RELEASE_1]
        ... 20 more
```

Within Karaf 4.0.0, the following spring features have been loaded:

```
@root()> feature:list | grep spring
spring                          | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Started     | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x support
spring-aspects                  | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Uninstalled | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x AOP support
spring-instrument               | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Uninstalled | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x Instrument support
spring-jdbc                     | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Started     | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x JDBC support
spring-jms                      | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Uninstalled | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x JMS support
spring-test                     | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Uninstalled | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x Test support
spring-orm                      | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  | x        | Started     | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x ORM support
spring-oxm                      | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Uninstalled | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x OXM support
spring-tx                       | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Started     | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x Transaction (TX) support
spring-web                      | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Uninstalled | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x Web support
spring-web-portlet              | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Uninstalled | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x Web Portlet support
spring-websocket                | 4.1.6.RELEASE_1                  |          | Uninstalled | spring-4.0.0             | Spring 4.1.x WebSocket support
spring-security                 | 3.1.4.RELEASE                    |          | Uninstalled | spring-4.0.0             | Spring Security 3.1.x support
```

In addition, my pom.xml is as follows:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>info.leonard.configuration</groupId>
    <artifactId>leonard-configuration-businessLogic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>info.leonard.configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>leonard-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../leonard-configuration</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <log4j-version>1.2.16</log4j-version>
        <slf4j-version>1.6.1</slf4j-version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.apache.felix.service.command;version="[0.6,1)",
                            org.apache.felix.gogo.commands;version="[0.6,1)",
                            org.apache.karaf.shell.console;version="[2.2,4)",
                            com.mysql.jdbc,
                            org.hibernate,
                            org.hibernate.cfg,
                            org.hibernate.service,
                            org.hibernate.jpa,
                            org.hibernate.proxy,
                            org.hibernate.annotations,
                            org.springframework.context.annotation,
                            org.springframework.orm.jpa,
                            org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor,
                            *,
                            javassist.util.proxy
                            info.leonard.foundation.common.*,
                            info.leonard.foundation.database.*,
                            info.leonard.foundation.environment.*,
                            info.leonard.foundation.exception.*,
                            info.leonard.foundation.finance.*,
                            info.leonard.foundation.finance.exception.*,
                            info.leonard.foundation.identity.*,
                            info.leonard.foundation.localization.*
                        </Import-Package>
                        <Export-Package>
                            info.leonard.configuration.data,
                            info.leonard.configuration.data.dao,
                            info.leonard.configuration.data.exception
                        </Export-Package>
                        <DynamicImport-Package>com.mysql.jdbc</DynamicImport-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.karaf.shell.console</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0.M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.enterprise</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.35</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.leonard.foundation</groupId>
            <artifactId>leonard-foundation-businessLogic</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4_3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.0-beta1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

It seems this is a classpath issue of some sorts:

- jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8832

My questions are:

- Have others have pursued and XML-less approach to initializing JPA within Karaf/OSGI, and can share their approach
- If this is a classpath issue preventing LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean from finding persistence.xml within resources/META-INF directory, is there a recommended solution for this?

Thanks in advance,
Randy

Comment: Don't use a `persistence.xml`. You have configured it to explicitly need one, don't and it should work without one. Also your setup seems rather complex why assign it to a static field and expose it with a get method?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I've commented out the lines to setPersistenceUnitName() and setPersistenceXmlLocation(), which was my original attempt.  But am still getting the same issue.  Do you suggest any other changes?

Comment: I would first clean up your configuration as that seems convoluted at first. You are managing bean callbacks yourself (which you shouldn't) your getter I don't really get why and you shouldn't assign it to a static instance variable. Just wondering is that the full stack trace I suspect there would be more. What I also don't get why on earth is a configuration class extending a class called `AbstractDao`???

Comment: Thanks again for your feedback, a few comments.  The entity is called Configuration, but it could be called anything.  It's just a database table, so let's rename this to XyzTable so we don't get hung up on that.  As for AbstractDao superclass, I'll just remove the superclass invocation altogether, it is unused (I've simply copied code from working Karaf code to test LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean).  As for callbacks, I'm not seeing that anywhere, so perhaps some clarification?  The stack trace is everything provided by Karaf.

Comment: But ultimately, the issue is with the first invocation of getEntityManagerFactory(), which attempts to instantiate an instance of LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.  Regardless of other context, it seems that code which works find outside of Karaf is not working within Karaf... as the code insists on looking for a persistence.xml file.  Not sure if this is a Karaf issue along the lines of this: jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8832.  Or if something else is at play.

Comment: One of the big issues I see with your code is that not spring is in control of the lifecycle, but you create the beans when they are requested and you are doing so by storing it into a static class variable. Which in OSGi can lead to some nice issues I guess. Also shouldn't you import the package you want to scan? (Been a while I messed around with OSGi).

Comment: You are probably on to something here ("is that not spring is in control of the lifecycle"), as my experience with Spring is a bit limited.  I will need to read up on using Spring within Karaf/OSGI and ensure this is all wired up correctly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would try to change your configuration to something like the following.

```
public class AbstractConfigurationServiceImpl extends AbstractDao {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        final MysqlDataSource dataSource = new MysqlDataSource();
        dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
        dataSource.setDatabaseName("PSH");
        dataSource.setUser("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        return dataSource;
    }


    @Bean
    public FactoryBean<EntityManagerFactory> entityManagerFactory()
    {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        emfBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "info.test.configuration.data" });
        emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        return emfBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter(){
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
        return jpaVendorAdapter;
    }

}
```

You don't really need the properties and setting the `JpaDialect` isn't needed because you are already setting the `JpaVendorAdapter`. You should also let Spring managed the lifecycle and not yourself.

One thing I wonder is why on earth is it extending `AbstractDao`, to me it looks like you are shoehorning a DAO approach into a configuration appraoch. Basically mixing concerns and responsibilities. This is also based on your stack trace.

In your service you should request an `EntityManager` and not get the `EntityManagerFactory`. If you really want to inject it but not use a configuration class as a base class.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ConfigurationDomainServiceImpl implements ConfigurationDomainService {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void createDomain(...) {
       Domain d = // do whatever is needed to create the domain.
       em.persist(domain);

    }
```

}

Comment: Much appreciated, will give this a try in a bit.  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work too well.  emfBean.getObject() returns null unless first calling emfBean.afterPropertiesSet().  After doing so, I still get the same stack trace.  Reviewing code in DefaultPersistenceUnitManager. determineDefaultPersistenceUnitRootUrl(), where exception occurs, seems clear Spring insists on loading a persistence.xml file...API documentation claims LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean doesn't need to load such files.  Perhaps Karaf/OSGI is introducing some unexpected twists?  I'll be walking through Spring code to figure this out, but additional ideas welcome.

Comment: Well the problem is that it isn't a `@Configuration` class as it should be, and as stated you should inject the dependency and not do `emfBean.getObject`. You aren't letting spring control the beans it should control. As I stated separate the concerns.

Comment: I agree... I'll be learning more about Spring and post my findings.  I appreciate your help.